# How to remove all files starting with a certain string in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I need to find all files starting with the name `NAME` in a directory tree and remove all these files using one shell command.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To delete all files which name has name, you can use it:

```
find  . -name 'name*' -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: You can also add -f as an 'rm' argument so you don't get prompted for "Are you sure you want to remove X file?"

Comment: Which version of `grep` has an `-exec` switch?

Comment: Why does this comment have downvotes?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321: probably because it's much the same as the earlier answers, and doesn't really add anything new.

Comment: In order to work for me (perhaps it is a timely change in the version) I left the negative (-) out of the -name, such as just 'name', then it worked.  Thank you for the solution!

Comment: This one works but it is dangerous, since it will delete files inside the current folder and its subdirectories.

Answer (score 87):

Delete all files in current directory and its sub-directories where the file name starts with "foo":

```
$ find . -type f -name foo\* -exec rm {} \;
```

NB: use with caution - back up first - also do a dry run first, e.g.

```
$ find . -type f -name foo\*
```

will just tell you the names of the files that would be deleted.

Comment: I had to delete over 2Million files and run in to trouble, `find . -type f -name foo\* -delete` did the trick

Answer (score 81):

I have tried this way it is working for me try below command.

```
rm -rf Example*
```

here "Example" is text which is common for all files.

Comment: Not sure why this isn't the highest-voted answer....

Comment: @DanTheMan It's because it's ~4 years newer than the other answers. This is definitely the most simple answer though.

Comment: This is my go-to to removing files like logs that build up. So much simpler than the "find" method that has been voted.

Comment: Plus, you can use tab to complete to make sure you spelled it right. Awesome.

Comment: This shouldn't be the highest-voted answer because it doesn't always work. Imagine if you have files in subfolders like A/Example1, B/Example2, C/Example3. You'd have to cd into each subfolder, or else it'll only search the root folder and not find anything.

Comment: I utterly destroyed my system with a slight typo doing this once...

Answer (score 12):

You can use `find`:

```
find . -name "name*" -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Also instead of specifying '.' you can specify an absolute path.

Answer (score 5):

`find . -name 'foo'* -type f -delete` seems like the simplest answer.

You can run this without the `-delete` flag before to see which files will be deleted.

Comment: As pointed out by @Linas `find . -type f -name foo\* -delete` works with files over 1M+, other solutions failed with ` Argument list too long`

Answer (score 4):

With the [`globstar` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) (enable with `shopt -s globstar`):

```
rm -f **/NAME*
```

`**/` expands to `./`, `*/`, `*/*/`, `*/*/*/` etc. If you have a *directory* name starting with `NAME`, the command will complain that `rm` can't remove directories, but that's all.

Notice that this might run into command line length limitations if the glob matches many files.

Alternatively, with as few invocations of `rm` as possible, but not subject to any command line length limitations:

```
find . -type f -name 'NAME*' -exec rm -f {} +
```

(Notice the `+` instead of `\;` to close the `-exec` statement.)

Answer (score 1):

Search for the "Inode" number of the file/folder and then delete using inode number. Below is an example:

```
ls -il
3407873 drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root      4096 Mar 30 07:49 –p

find . -inum 3407873 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: This is a good answer — to a *different* question.  It’s not an answer to *this* question.

Comment: But it answered the question I had when I searched and found this one. Are we so pedantic we can't have closely-related answers? Short on storage space? I hope the SO and related are _useful_ repositories - not exemplary samples of rule-following.